# Entity Framework 6 - Inserting/Updating 2 table joined by a view

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my database I have

1. a Members table which contains basic member details (MemberId [primary key - auto generated number], MemberName, IsActive).
2. a MembersDetails table which contains more detailed information about the member (Address, Phone, Birthday ...). MembersDetails has MemberId field as a foreign key to the Members table.

There's a reason (part of the app logic) that the 2 tables are separated and are not all in one table.

I've created a view that gets a full member details (a join of the 2 tables), and Entity Framework created an object that represents the view.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a better way of flattening 2 joined tables into an object other than creating a view in the database?
2. I would like to create an object of the view type (a full user details), initialize it's properties and insert it to the database (which will put the info it needs in the Members table, the the generated id, and than insert to the MemberDetails table). Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Ad 1.**

I think a database view will be a good choice for performance reasons.

But you can investigate an inheritance provided with the Entity Framework. 

It allows you join two separated tables in one model object containing all properties (from "derived" and "base" table). Note, it will be OK for one to one relations (but not for one to many).
[Implementing Inheritance with the Entity Framework 6 in an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

**Ad 2.**

The Entity Framework inheritance will help you with this issue well. Alternatively, if you can use a database view, just create stored procedures for inserting and updating data included in a view, then map the stored procedures for specified actions on the view model generated by Entity Framework.

Comment: Entity splitting would probably be a better option.